# There is no internet connectivity in Vmware VM after changing wifi routers

Tags: windows-10, wireless-networking, dns, vmware

Ever since I changed my router from Asus RT-AC55U to Asus RT-AX53U I can't get internet connectivity on my Vmware machines (Windows 10). Setting it to bridged mode doesn't help.
If I connect to my old router, configured now as a repeater, it works and continues working even if I then connect to my new router network. I did notice it sets 192.168.50.2 as DNS server and gateway which is wrong, it should be 192.168.50.1. But even if I set it manually it doesn't work.
I'm really puzzled why it sets it incorrectly in the first place since everything else works without any problems, except for VMs. I've tried everything I can think of (admittedly I'm lacking a bit in this area) but it still won't work out of the box.

Comment: The external router should not bother a VMware Virtual Machine (I am using a VMware VM right now).  Close any open VMs.  Run the Virtual Network Editor (Edit Menu in VMware V17; an App in prior versions). Reset the VMware Network, close out, restart and test.

Comment: I agree, but... I was actually using Vmware Player, so I installed Workstation to try your suggestion and it suddenly works without me doing anything. #confused
I will try it a bit more later.

Comment: Do you have MAC address filtering enabled on the new router?  You say "Setting it to bridged mode doesn't help", but using bridged mode would make your VMs *more* susceptible to connectivity problems from changing routers, not less.  If you instead use NAT, then they should have internet connectivity if your host has internet connectivity and should be more agnostic to changes to your physical network.

Comment: There was nothing wrong with my answer - why downvoted?  I answered the question properly about resetting the network and that worked. Using NAT without resetting may or may not work. Downvoting on a "maybe" is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

> Ever since I changed my router from Asus RT-AC55U to Asus RT-AX53U I
> can't get internet connectivity on my Vmware machines

The external router should not bother a VMware Virtual Machine (I am using a VMware VM right now). Close any open VMs. Run the Virtual Network Editor (Edit Menu in VMware V17; an App in prior versions). Reset the VMware Network, close out, restart and test.

Your action of replacing VMware Player with VMware Workstation essentially resets the internal network as I suggested.

Reinstalling VMware Workstation or reinstalling VMware Player is another approach to resetting the internal VMware network - that is quite normal.

Comment: I see, thank you. For future reference, do I reset the network by clicking the "Restore Defaults" button?

Comment: Yes, in the Virtual Network Settings do that and restart. That has always worked for me.

Comment: "The external router should not bother a VMware Virtual Machine" That is not necessarily true, especially when using bridged networking where the router might be doing MAC address filtering or other packet inspection. It also wouldn't be true if the VM is using a static networking configuration instead of DHCP. "Reinstalling ...is another approach to resetting the internal VMware network - that is quite normal." Needing to reinstall Workstation/Player is *not* normal.  If you need to do that to fix a problem, then that's a bug.

Comment: Reinstalling the VMware apps is not a bug of any kind. It can fix problems including networking. I have use VMware since V1 so I do not know where your misinformation comes from.

Comment: Read my profile.  While reinstalling can fix problems, unless the user explicitly did something to break their installation, reinstallation is never the expected solution. Problems should be fixable without doing so; reinstallation usually is a last resort.

Comment: Reinstallation is a workable solution for many Apps, VMware included.